# UI hang before Call back of SignalR

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr, signalr-hub

Im using signalR for sending data here is my code to send data.

```
            manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
            manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
            manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
            [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            setUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[UtilHelper sharedManager].WebServiceURL,@"Save"];
            NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:dicArray,@"products", nil];

            __block NSMutableArray* json;
            json = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [manager POST:setUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                NSError *writeError = nil;
                NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
                NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                      error:&writeError];
                if ([[dic valueForKey:@"StatusMsg"] isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
                    //  save To S3 Bucket
                    [self sendPicture:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strProductId] : strPackageId];
                    [[results objectAtIndex:i] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"productsync"];
                    [[results objectAtIndex:i] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"editflag"];
                    [context save:nil];

                }
            }
                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                  }];
```

Now im getting SignalR response in `AppDelegate`

```
[hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *message) {
    NSLog(@"%@",message);

    });
```

When setReceived called my UI hand here is my code that i present my `UIViewController`  that i present and hang UI init

```
-(void)handlePlusOption{

    __weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        __strong __typeof(&*weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

    strongSelf.addProductVc = [[AddProductVC alloc] initWithNibName:addProductVcIdentifier bundle:nil];
    strongSelf.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:strongSelf.addProductVc];
    strongSelf.nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    strongSelf.nav.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    strongSelf.nav.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = NO; // To hide status bar, doest work with UIModalPresentationPageSheet style
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:strongSelf.nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
    });
}
```

Why UI hang before `setReceived` ?

Answer (score 0):

> try to put your setReceived block of code inside this block ..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // time-consuming task
    [hubConnection setReceived:^(NSString *message) {
         NSLog(@"%@",message);
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // run in main thread 
    });

});
```

Comment: It's same i already try that, and my UI is hang before setReceived is called.

Comment: try put setReceived block in main thread below  ..this may work or you could use another way to send you data using sbjson parser lib if you are sending json data.

Comment: Nah, its still same. and im getting key-value in response and my data is not that large that hang UI its just 6 Key-Value pair. Is that possible to it because of server side that send data ?

Comment: @bhadresh i didn't get you ..simply you want to send json data to server which has only 6 key value pair ?

Comment: okay change your approach with the following link ..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37110874/4003548

Comment: There's no problem in sending data, it's response who got problem.